# Чи є в українській мові відповідник до слова "тренування"?

Tags: відповідник

Слово [тренування](http://sum.in.ua/s/trenuvannja) - навчання, вправи для вдосконалення навику, майстерності. Утворене від дієслова "тренувати", що було запозичене з англійської мови ([ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=629), ст. 629).

Як бачимо, слово є в СУМі і сьогодні його можна почути дуже часто. Однак, цікавить чи є якийсь український відповідник, бо пошуки на Словотворі та в Інтернеті нічого не дали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3і «Словника української мови» в 20 томах:

> [ВПРА́ВА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=16220&page=538), и, *ж*. 1. *Розвиток певних якостей, навичок постійною, систематичною роботою. Вивчила недавно .. граматику [італійську] і тепер для вправи читаю книжки* (Леся Українка);
>   *Щоденна вправа на добрім інструменті здавалася їй перспективою на недалекий побут [перебування] в консерваторії* (О. Кобилянська); // Спроба опанувати якусь справу, набути певного вміння. *Тепер не пригадую, щоб у семінарії я оддавався своїм літературним вправам* (С. Васильченко); *Поштар теж побачив у вікно дідові вправи на велосипеді* (О. Донченко).
>
> <…>
>
> ---
>
> [ВПРАВЛЯ́ТИ<sup>2</sup>](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=16233&page=538), я́ю, я́єш, *недок.*, *кого, що і без прям. дод*. Постійною працею, практикою розвивати, вдосконалювати певні риси характеру, навички тощо; тренувати. *Касян завів такий порядок, що одні йшли до хазяйської роботи, других вправляв у воєннім ремеслі: вчились їздити на коні, стріляти в ціль, поводитися з гарматою* (А. Чайковський); *– Ти також можеш дуже добре грати, хоч інакше. Тільки пильно вправляй. Без праці далеко не зайдеш* (Б. Лепкий); *Людина вправляє свою вищу нервову діяльність шляхом систематичної розумової та фізичної праці* (з навч. літ.).
>
> ---
>
> [ВПРАВЛЯ́ТИСЯ<sup>2</sup>](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=16236&page=538), я́юся, я́єшся, *недок.*, *у чому, також із чого*. Постійними, систематичними заняттями, виконанням певних вправ розвивати й удосконалювати які-небудь уміння та навички. *– Я дуже зайнятий студіями... Крім того, даю лекції, вправляюсь сам багато в музиці...* (О. Кобилянська); *– Патер Алоїзій навмисне водить мене до Жолкєвських вправлятися з латині* (З. Тулуб); *Дехто спав, інші вправлялися в стрільбі* (С. Воскрекасенко); // Робити певні вправи на спортивних приладах. *Юрко пішов у фізкультурний зал, де на трапеціях і брусах вправлялися школярі* (О. Донченко);
>   *Ми зачудовано дивилися, як на кільцях та брусах хвацько вправляються хлопчаки й дівчата* (Є. Доломан); // *ірон*. Займатися чим-небудь. *Вони вже, напевно, десь там стоять на могилі, позадиравши голови, і вправляються в саркастичних дотепах...* (О. Довженко).

Як я розумію особисто для себе, тренуватися — це навчатися чомусь *на практиці*, тобто це частковий випадок слова *навчатися* — навчатися можна і теоретично, і практично, а слово *тренуватися* робить акцент на практичному засвоєнні навичок. Відповідно також можна використовувати *навчати*/*навчатися*/*навчання* (але ці слова мають ширше значення) або в деяких випадках *практикуватися*/*практика* (але ці слова можуть мати інше значення, бо мова може йти про різні рівні практичності; і вони теж іншомовного походження).

Answer (score 3):

Доволї широке слово, оскільки навчанє і вдосконаленє дешчо ріжні понятя. Лїпше, гадаю, описати сӧго слова як «тримати чи розвинути до певного рівня».

Таким чином добре підходить слово *підготовка* від [*підготовити*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidghotovljaty)

> 2. *також до чого*. Давати необхідний запас знань, передавати навички, досвід і т. ін. в процесі навчання, практичної діяльності.
>
>    //  *у сполуч. із сл. себе*. Набувати певних знань, навичок, досвіду і т. ін.

Окрім сӧго існують також наступні, але вже не так вживані чи поза тим складніші для вживу

> [ВИ́УЧКА, и, *жін.*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyuchka)
>
> 1. *розм.* Дія за значенням *виучувати*, *виучити*.
> 2. Сукупність знань, навиків, здобутих внаслідок навчання чому-небудь.

Слово *заправа* (і взагалі подальші від *права* як *вправа*) від [*заправляти*](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8&highlight=on)

> дрессировать, выдрессировать, натаскать;

Answer (score 2):

[відточую](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14076&page=455) (-свої навички/майстеріність/вимову/тіло(вставка))

Те, що треба для повсякденного використання.

(↓правка↓)

> А training, јак і украјинське тренуванье мо' значити також і те, шчо
>   вчать з 0. Навіть јакшчо про сього забути, то відточенье маје на увазі
>   вивід чогось јакісного. Сьебто ја тренују мову та ја відточују мову —
>   мајуть инші забарвлень. Тому, будь ласка, појасніть, чому «те шчо тре'
>   дльа повсьакденного вживу».

Наприклад, колись довелося перекласти таке речення "i'm back! were you doing some training?"
Яку я переклав як: я повернулася! відточуєш свої навички?
(для пояснення ситуації: хлопець колись професійно займався невідомою мені діяльністю, пов'язаною із фехтуванням, а дівчина перед тим як запитала побачила, що він повторював замахи зброєю)

> ...шчо вчать з 0...

На мою думку неможливо щось вчити з нуля, бо у всіх є якісь початкові задатки від матінки природи та тоді вже слід використовувати слово "[засвоїти](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=32242&page=1042)" або "[оволодіти](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15731&page=521)"

Comment: Тут запитували про јменник. Отже _відточенье_? Слово непогане, так. Але, нмд, _відточенье_ — сье коли польіпшујуть чогось, А _training_, јак і украјинське _тренуванье_ мо' значити також і те, шчо вчать з 0. Навіть јакшчо про сього забути, то _відточенье_ маје на увазі вивід чогось јакісного. Сьебто _ја тренују мову_ та _ја відточују мову_ — мајуть инші забарвлень. Тому, будь ласка, појасніть, чому «те шчо тре' дльа повсьакденного вживу».

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті Ukrainian Language.SE! Почитайте, будь ласка, як мають виглядати відповіді на нашому сайті: [хороші запитання й відповіді](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/240). Скоріш за все, цю відповідь будуть мінусувати, але не знічуйтесь. Просто продовжуйте пробувати. Сподіваємось на плідну співпрацю.